# Group by to find max per group and then count the groups that have their max values in each year

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I'm trying to group the variables by their max values and then count the number of groups that have their max values in a certain period.

The data set looks like this:

| Year | Car | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1991 | A | 21 |
| 1992 | A | 19 |
| 1993 | A | 20 |
| 1992 | B | 42 |
| 1993 | B | 17 |
| 1991 | C | 31 |
| 1992 | C | 50 |
| 1993 | C | 23 |

What I want to do is to find the max values per car and then count how many cars reached their maximum values per year.

So essentially, a table like this

| Year | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1991 | 1 |
| 1992 | 2 |
| 1993 | 0 |

I was able to identify the max values per group using dplyr but cant figure out how to implement the count. Can someone please help? I've also tried top_n but that just gives me the max value per month which isnt what I want!

Comment: In your sample data set all cars have their max values in 1992 but the expected result does not reflect this. Please, can you clarify - thank you.

Comment: Another question: What is the expected answer in case a car hits the maximum value in in more than one year, e.g., Car A has a Value of 21 in 1991 *and* 1992?

Comment: @Uwe : Great question! In that case I would want both the years to be counted.

Answer (score 2):

Very close to Ben's code! Without `n_distinct`

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(Car) %>%  
  mutate(mx = max(Value)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  summarise(count=sum(Value >= mx))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The example output does not match the example data, but this might be what you are looking for.

First, `group_by` Car and determine the maximum value for that particular Car. Then, you can `group_by` Year, and count up using `n_distinct` the number of unique Cars, where the `Value` is equal to the maximum value.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Car) %>%
  mutate(Max_Value = max(Value)) %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  summarise(Count = n_distinct(Car[Value == Max_Value]))
```

**Output**

```
   Year Count
  <int> <int>
1  1991     0
2  1992     3
3  1993     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `dplyr` way :

Keep only the max `Value` rows in every `Year` and `count` `Year`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Year = factor(Year)) %>%
  group_by(Car) %>%
  slice(which.max(Value)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  count(Year, .drop = FALSE)

#  Year      n
#* <fct> <int>
#1 1991      0
#2 1992      3
#3 1993      0
```